# Is it a good practice in Redux to dispatch multiple reducers and cases in a single action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two reducers: `errorReducer` and `userReducer`.

I have a `login` action:

```
export const login = (login) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/login", login).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.token) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data,
            });
            dispatch({
                type: CLEAR_ERROR,
            });
        } else if (res.data.status === "Invalid credentials.") {
            dispatch({
                type: ERROR,
                payload: res.data.status,
            });
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see, if the login fails, there is an error. An error message appears for the user. However, if the login is successful, then I need to clear the error state with another dispatch. Is this a good practice? If I don't do this, then the error will stay in the state and that's not good I guess.

And if I login successfully for the first try, the `CLEAR_ERROR` runs too, I don't want that.

How can I reset the `ERROR` case in the `login` action without dispatching?

I am planning to make a loadingReducer as well, but then I will need to dispatch that too. Isn't that too many? Is there a way around this? I could put error and loading in the userReducer, but I'm not sure if that's a good practice either.

errorReducer:

```
import { ERROR, CLEAR_ERROR } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = [];

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ERROR:
            return action.payload;
        case CLEAR_ERROR:
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

userReducer:

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    user: {},
    authenticated: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                authenticated: true,
                ...action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an effect to show an error message in a toaster for example. Not storing it in the state.

If you do want to keep it in the state then you could state that a successful login implies that the error should be empty. So you could handle that in the LOGIN_SUCCESS case.

Your states in both reducers do not match though. They should be the same object. So make a file somewhere that exports the initialState and use that in both reducers.

Comment: If you have the time, could you please edit your answer and elaborate the 1st and 3rd with some code example? I'm learning learning Redux now and it would help a lot. Thank you anyways!

Comment: " If you do want to keep it in the state then you could state that a successful login implies that the error should be empty. So you could handle that in the LOGIN_SUCCESS case. " - this is a good solution.